# PHP read from file into array and remove duplicates (loop)

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, duplicates, text-files

I've googled a bit now, but can't find anything that works for me.

I have a textfile containing:
username;firstname;lastname;classcode\n

I use this while-loop to get content out:

```
$handle = fopen("studen.txt", "r");

while(!feof($handle)) {

$linje = fgets($handle);

$larray = explode(";",$linje);

$klassekode = trim($larray[3]);

}
```

$larray[3] is the only thing I'm interested in here. I want to make a html-list out of this, so I used:

```
echo "<option value=\"$klassekode\">$klassekode</option>";
```

My problem now is that I can't seem to find a way to remove the duplicate entries. There are now 3 "IS1", 4 "IS3" and so on. I suspect there's a easy solution for this that I simply can't figure out :-|

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an aside, isn't your classcode in `$larray[2]` as the result from `explode()` will be zero-based?

Comment: Sorry, it's username;firstname;lastname;classcode. Therefore $larray[3] equals ex IS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way, without much code modification, would be to keep a second array of every value you've already seen and if the current value exists in it, skip it:

```
$seenValues = array();

$handle = fopen("studen.txt", "r");
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $linje = fgets($handle);
    $larray = explode(";",$linje);
    $klassekode = trim($larray[3]);

    if (in_array($klassekode, $seenValues)) continue; // skip it
    $seenValues[] = $klassekode;
    // do your other stuff
}
```

Using the same method as above, but more efficient, would be to use the `$klassekode` value as the index in the `$seenValues` array and use PHP's `isset()` instead. It's *way* faster than using the `in_array()` method, so if there are a lot of these entries and speed is important, try this instead:

```
...
if (isset($seenValues[$klassekode])) continue; // skip it
$seenValues[$klassekode] = true;
...
```

Comment: or just
if(!in_array($klassekode, $seenValues))
   $seenValues[] = $klassekode;

Comment: Perfect! :-D Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_unique` to remove duplicate and `file` to read the file in to an array

```
$content = array_unique(file("studen.txt"));
foreach ( $content as $var ) {
    list($userame, $klassekode, $klassekode) = explode(";", $var);
    printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $klassekode, $klassekode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since classcode is the 3rd field in the line it is available in `$larray[2]` and not in `$larray[3]`.

Next to de-duplicate you can make use of another array. Arrays in PHP can act like hashes or sets. Every time you explode and get a new class code you put it in an array and at the end you just use the elements from this array as your classcodes.